# How to do find/replace case insensitive only in the beginning part of the string?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I want to remove "I will" at the beginning of a string.  Those "I will" words could be uppercase/lowercase, so I will need to match for case insensitive. But I only want to remove those words if they are **at the beginning** of the string.

I tried .replace(), but that doesn't take into account the situations above.

Comment: I think you need to put a bit more effort on your questions. At least show the code you tried.

Comment: In javascript, [you cannot](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html). You need to use the `|` in your pattern.

Comment: @BoristheSpider - What do you mean you "cannot"? JS regexes can be case insensitive, and pretty much any language's regex syntax (including JS's) lets you match a pattern at the start of the string. There's no need for `|` for this purpose. TIMEX - `.replace()` _does_ take your requirements into account since it accepts a regex and the regex needed here is quite simple. Have you read through any regex tutorials?

Comment: I was referring to the "at the beginning" part. Javascript does not support modifier spans so you cannot have the beginning be case insensitive and the rest of the pattern case sensitive.

Comment: @BoristheSpider - There'll be no "rest of the pattern" here. OP has only mentioned matching a specific phrase if and only if it is at the beginning, so `/^i will/i` does it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the *ignore case* flag `i`:

```
var x = "I will write good code";

// the ^ at the start tells it to match from the beginning
// the i flag tells it to ignore case
x = x.replace(/^i\s+will\s+/i, '');

// Outputs: "write good code" regardless of the case of "i will"
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to replace all the spaces and line brakes (when we press enter) and bring every thing down in one line from a text input box. It'll help me a lot!

Comment: @Ishpreet - Thats so unlike how it should be done in SO. Post it as a question and someone will help you out.

Comment: they have stopped me from asking any question for a day, so please tell me in comment if you can!

Comment: @Ishpreet - Text inputs can't have line breaks. Do you mean a `<textarea>` element? When you say "replace all the spaces" do you really mean you want to remove _all_ space charaters, even between words on one line? `.replace(/\s/g,'')` should do it, since `\s` matches all white space characters including newline and carriage return...